# How to add an application icons to the desktop in 14.04?

Tags: .desktop

How does one add an application icon to the desktop in verson 14.04?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Using [Avinash Raj's](https://askubuntu.com/users/202806/avinash-raj) response, I simply used files to locate the app, right clicked, copied, and pasted. The created desktop file did not need to be edited at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First copy your desired application's icon from the `/usr/share/applications` directory to Desktop,

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/filename.desktop ~/Desktop
```

Then change the permissions(*give execute permission to the .desktop file*) of copied `.desktop` file on the Desktop,

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/filename.desktop
```

Double click on the application icon to run it's corresponding application.

Comment: get rid of the lock with:
sudo chown username:groupname ~/Desktop/*.desktop

Comment: Don't think that you need sudo...

Comment: Not sure whether this was already available in version 14, but now you can also put the `.desktop` in `.local/share/applications/`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a symbolic link in the desktop folder to the file you want to execute. 
Open a terminal session and change to your Desktop folder:

```
cd Desktop
```

To create the desktop icon use:

```
ln -sv "target file to execute" "filename to create for shortcut" (no quotes)
```

I tried it with Nautilus and it worked fine. So far all of the icons I have created work, but they don't get an identifying icon, just the AptURL icon.

Here's the example I created for Nautilus:

```
ln -sv /usr/bin/nautilus "File Manager"
```

The icon appeared on the desktop and it works fine, as have the others I made.
You do need to be able to find the executable files, which means you need to know some Linux, but otherwise it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another easy way to do it:

1) Open Nautilus, navigate to "Computer".

```
$ sudo nautilus
```

-provide your password credentials

2) Navigate to folder /usr/share/applications

3) In that folder, select the program of your choice (for example, System Monitor).Now Drag it to your desktop or copy & paste it.
That's it!

Your Desktop icon is created.

Comment: +1 this is the best way for 2 reasons: first of all it's easy to copy more then one program, and secondly because it copies also the icon.