# Gnome and Xfce at the same time?

Tags: gnome, xfce

I thought that I had changed my Ubuntu to a Xubuntu by switching to xfce desktop (Ubuntu 20.04). Though, when I enter `gnome-shell --version` in the terminal, I get `GNOME Shell 3.36.1`.

When I enter `printenv | grep XDG` I get:

`XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/mafalda
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop`

And `sudo dpkg -l | grep gnome` lists a lot of GNOME packages.

Is that normal? I am trying to tidy up my system a little after recognizing I had several screensavers installed that were maybe interfering with each other.

Does Xfce need the GNOME packages (like gnome-bluetooth, gnome-power-manager...), or can I uninstall them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xfce is well-designed desktop, so it have needed components for bluetooth, power and so on.
I would recommend to save GNOME Disk Utility in your Xfce system (`gnome-disk-utility` package).

If not sure what to remove - you can always run a simulation of packages removal with special APT option:

```
apt-get remove --simulate gnome-control-center
```

and then decide to remove the package with `sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center` or not.

If you want to remove GNOME Stuff completely - you can use the list from [my other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509), but be careful.

Comment: In your link, what does the ^ in `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop^` do?

Comment: It installs big meta-package (really task) with all needed dependencies for Xubuntu.

Comment: And another question: If I do remove GNOME entirely, e.g. by `sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-desktop`, or by the long part of code you posted in the linked thread, could it break the software I installed, the preferences I set (in non-GNOME apps) or sth similar? I would really like to clean up unnecessary double applications, but am still a bit afraid ;)

Comment: The configuration files in your home-folder (something like `~/.config` and other dot-folders) will remain here, GSettings and Dcont settings will not be changed. I have tested the long command in linked tread on VM, but if you are unsure - you can run it with `--simulate` first and then edit final list of packages to be removed.

Comment: Ok, now I ran `sudo apt-get purge --simulate` with the list of all the GNOME packages from your link, except `gnome-disk-utility`. What seems strange to me is that according to the terminal, it tries to purge several `xfce4` packages. Why is that?
And: When does it start (or stop) to "simulate"?