# How to remove gnome settings from ubuntu 20.04 with unity desktop?

Tags: 20.04

I have ubuntu 20.04 with unity desktop. I removed the existing gnome shell and now when I search for settings I have two of them one is the system settings and the other is the gnome settings. How can I remove the gnome settings from ubuntu 20.04

Comment: try "sudo apt remove gnome-control-center"

Answer (score 8):

After you've install **Unity Desktop** and, logged into it, use:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt remove gnome-shell
```

This works for for Ubuntu **16.04** to **20.04** and even **20.10** (Groovy). Source:

- [Ubuntu – How to remove Gnome Desktop Environment without messing Unity DE? (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-remove-gnome-desktop-environment-without-messing-unity-de-ubuntu-16-04/)

---

Although article is written for Ubuntu **16.04**, you can verify the package is still around for **20.04** (called Focal) by visiting [Package: ubuntu-gnome-desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-gnome-desktop):

[image: ubuntu-gnome-deskop package.png]

---

Personally I use **Unity** all the time but like to keep both desktops installed. Occasionally I need to answer other users' questions about **Gnome Desktop**.

---

### Note: `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` might not be installed

Because it is a transitional package since 18.04 these instructions from:

- [Why and How to Install Unity 7 Desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-unity-desktop-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Tell you to simply use:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell
```

The article doesn't mention `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` needing to be removed. This article includes additional tips on setting up **Unity Desktop**.

Comment: Should probably also add a "sudo apt autoremove" to remove all automatically installed packages of these desktop environments? Only then, gnome-settings may be effectively removed.

Comment: @vanadium The link discusses that plus at lot more. I debated myself how much of the link to include. Perhaps you wouldn't mind visiting the link and giving me your thoughts on amount of details to include in my answer?

Comment: Policy of this site is to include all relevant stuff, so the anwer is self containing. Anyway, the link probably is not anymore up to date: `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` currently is a transitional package that is not even installed by default.

Comment: @vanadium You are correct it has been transitional package since **Ubuntu 18.04** and I've revised answer to reflect that. I appreciate your input.