# How can I add Ubuntu Unity Desktop to existing Ubuntu 20.04 installation?

Tags: unity

I find that Unity Desktop is back on new distribution Ubuntu Unity.
Can I install this Unity Desktop on existing Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that you have to follow the following steps.

1. Install Unity Desktop Environment
2. Set LightDM as your default Display Manager(Optional)
3. Then While logging in choose Unity from session manager.

1st thing first, fire up terminal then try `$ sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`
This will help to install ubuntu unity desktop and other relevant packages

In the mean time it will pop-up display manager configuration information. Use tab key to navigate to `lightdm` and hit `ok`.

(**It's very unlikely you have to follow this step**)If for any reason LightDm won't get installed. You can mannually install by `$sudo apt install lightdm`. And to go Display manager configuration information use `$ sudo update-alternatives --config lightdm`.

Reboot your pc. Then if everything goes straight then you can see lightdm login screen instead of gdm3 login screen.

Then Enter password, Mark the ubuntu logo besides your user name (It's the session manager). Click here and choose `Unity(Default)`.

Wow here you get Ubuntu running Unity desktop. If you decide to stick with unity and remove gnome-shell, you can follow the link [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) .

Otherwise before logging in you can always select Ubuntu(Gnome one) or Unity from the session manager. If you once select Unity It will be selected by default unless you won't change.

Thanks and Regards

Sabyasachi Rout