# How can I use the 16.04 gui on 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, gui

As I personally don't like the way 20.04 works (mainly settings and activities) I would like to use the 16.04 gui. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: If you upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 and then to 20.04 you retain the Unity desktop but you may need to select it at the sign on screen which can default to Gnome. After you select it once though it will retain that setting until you change it again. You can actually have 5 different desktops after upgrade: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035446/upgraded-to-ubuntu-18-04-but-i-still-have-old-ui/1035452#1035452

Comment: This is not an official flavor of Ubuntu, but it is actively maintained, and would have better user experience than manually installing Unity on Ubuntu. http://ubuntuunity.org/

Comment: There is a chance the Ubuntu-Unity re-spin may become an official flavor later this year..  They were working towards that goal...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add Ubuntu Unity Desktop to existing Ubuntu 20.04 installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250788/how-can-i-add-ubuntu-unity-desktop-to-existing-ubuntu-20-04-installation)

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 16.04 defaulted to the Unity 7 desktop.

Ubuntu 17.10 & later use the GNOME desktop by default.

Use

`sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`

to install (add) the Unity 7 desktop on your system.  You can select which you use at login.

Comment: Note the Unity 7 desktop will only have 3 years of support; not the 5 provided for GNOME or the default desktop.  Also it's slightly different now to what it was in 16.04 (due to changes upstream or the libraries mostly), but it's the same Unity 7 desktop.  There are pros & cons to it like all things.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you get Unity 7.5 when you install now days.

Comment: Unity & GNOME aren't my *cup of tea* so I don't monitor them very closely..

Comment: My cup of tea would be Earl Grey but it's a little too expensive so I usually revert to Red Rose :) What desktop do you use then? Something like Mate?

Comment: I was invited to join the Lubuntu team, so LXQt became my default desktop (what i'm using now though I have mulitple DEs installed on my boxes). I still like & use XFCE heaps, but LXQt has become my home... @WinEunuuchs2Unix