# Multiple item drag'n'drop on Desktop, with mouse, doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, desktop-icons, drag-and-drop

On Ubuntu 20.04, when I select multiple files on Desktop and move them (either moving icons around on desktop, or moving multiple files to Trash), only the item over which mouse is residing gets moved, the rest are left behind. As a result, I am unable to do multi-icon mouse drag'n'drop actions on Desktop. This behavior doesn't happen when I move files in File manager, across windows and/or folders.

Thoughts?

Comment: Desktop icon management in Ubuntu 20.04 is incomplete. Some features like drag and drop doesn't work properly (or are not fully implemented).

Check also these questions for further details:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254037/dragndrop-files-desktop-file-manager-with-20-04-lts-doesnt-work-it-work