# Application launchers in '/usr/share/applications' not working in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, icons, .desktop

After installing the latest Ubuntu I find that the icons in the applications folder (viz. `/usr/share/applications`), when opened in the *Files* application (Nautilus), come up as a blank page with a gear in the middle. If I try to open them I get a read only text box.

[image: Screen Shot Image]

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to new brave world of modern GNOME Shell "desktop".

It is a [bug 1819375](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1819375) caused by upstream Nautilus [simplification](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/184).

You have to use other fully-functional modern file-managers like Caja, Dolphin, Konqueror, Nemo, PCManFM or Thunar.

---

If you want to get normal fully-integrated non-surprising desktop back - remove GNOME Shell and install other normal desktop. You may want to follow [my Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233025/66509) to do so. My recommendation is to install MATE DE instead.