# Cannot open .desktop files from nautilus in ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, .desktop, 20.10

I searched a lot to find information about why I can't open .desktop files from nautilus but in  vain. Well I could open .desktop in Ubuntu 20.04 but in Groovy Gorilla, No I can't. I tried changing preferences but none came to any help either. And When I choose to be asked whether to open or edit in preferences then a dialog box does crop up and I click `Run` it just vanishes and nothing happens. But I can run these files from desktop well because this isn't part of nautilus I guess.

I know it's not that important but though when I remember I could do that in previous version I can't help but try this to make possible.

So any help here? And as a side note, I saw lots of videos which they even have icons in .desktop files(might be 19.10 or so).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application launchers in '/usr/share/applications' not working in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254375/application-launchers-in-usr-share-applications-not-working-in-nautilus) - simply do not use Nautilus.

Comment: @N0rbert, Yeah, I understand maybe I just have to switch over. btw, I was talking talking about any folder in general especially Home and its subdirectories under which focal worked(well maybe not 'cause I had then installed Kde so, you know, it was maybe just like equating dolphin with nautilus and mis-memorizing)