# Accidentally installed Gnome GUI on Ubuntu Server; how do I get rid of it?

Tags: server, gnome

I'm not sure which package I installed that also installed Gnome GUI. I did deluge (not just deluge-console) by accident, so maybe that was it. Or it could be gcp maybe?

Either way, now that I boot up my server when attached to a monitor, it has a basic Gnome GUI that can't do anything (no apps except vim and byobu terminal).

In either case, I have Gnome now and I want to get rid of it. And possibly purge any other packages that were accidentally installed.

```
sudo apt list
```

Returns way too many results for me to filter through. Is there a way to at least get rid of Gnome easily?

And is there a way to list how much storage each package uses?

Comment: You can run `zgrep 'install ' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | cut -f1,2,4 -d' '` and identify the packages installed recently related to GNOME. `apt list` returns available packages (installed and available for installation). You may consider using `--installed` option with the command, i.e., `apt list --installed`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it was deluge. I've removed deluge and installed only deluge-console. I've also done 'sudo apt autoremove' which should've uninstalled all of the X11 and GUI stuff right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If you still have some packages dependent on X11 or Wayland, they might still be there in your system. You can check using `apt-cache policy xorg`. Also, I'm not sure which GNOME GUI you installed, for example, `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, `gnome`, etc.

Comment: @jkang You can check first part of my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509).