# How to remove all the packages that come with gnome?

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, uninstall, delete

I have recently switched from gnome to unity and have removed gnome with

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt remove gnome-shell
```

I have also purged config files like below

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Removed unwanted dependencies with

```
sudo apt auto-remove
```

But I don't know how to delete all the bloatware that comes with gnome.
When I run

```
sudo apt list gnome-*
```

It gives me a huge list which is really difficult to remove manually.
How can I remove the apps like settings, calendar music and so on without manually deleting them one by one?

Comment: This is easier said then done, because a lot of Gnome3 packages are needed for Unity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) - be careful

Comment: Use unity also, find no problem with leaving gnome alone as a secondary desktop on system.  Might want or need to do this with other desktops, but with unity would leave things as they are.

Comment: I would have left unity alone but in my search when I type for example settings I get two apps and similarly for other apps therefore to Clean this up I thought about deleting the whole gnome thing.