# RShift + LShift works together with LAlt + LShift to switch language layout. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have two languages as input sources: us, ru.

By default there is only Win+Space keyboard shortcut to switch between them.

When I enable **only** LAlt + LShift shortcut with Tweaks:

[image]

the shortcut starts to work as expected, but along with it I have RShift + LShift enabled, which also switches languages in the same way. It is very annoying, as when typing fast it switches unintentionally two times per minute.

Is there any way to enable the only LAlt + LShift to switch it?

UPDATE:

```
glaz@glaz-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
glaz@glaz-ubuntu:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
@as []
glaz@glaz-ubuntu:~$ gsettings get org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey triggers
['<Super>space']
glaz@glaz-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Only RShift + LShift works, but not LShift + RShift.

Comment: If it behaves as you describe, it sounds as a bug to me and should be [reported as such](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to new brave world of GNOME Shell.
For now it will switch keyboard when it wants. It does not listen the user. It ignores the settings.

There is only one fix for this - completely remove GNOME Shell from the system and install normal desktop instead, and [here is how](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233025/66509). I have just tested this behavior on MATE - it works as expected.

---

Note: as a good will, I reported this issue against GNOME Shell to launchpad as [bug 1888940](https://pad.lv/1888940).
What is really interesting - the issue exists since Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.