# How to install Nautilus 3.26 in Ubuntu 20.04 and get updates in unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I recently (manually) upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and I'm not liking this new Nautilus 3.28 at all. I can't decrease the desktop font size from `gsetting set org.gnome.nautilus.dekstop`
Besides I'm going to purge gnome desktop and install unity anyway. So is there any way to roll back the Nautilus?

I also didn't get any update in 18.04 because I used unity. Can that be solved somehow in 20.04 without using gnome?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) . Unity will use the same version of Nautilus. So it is no way. Use MATE or Cinnamon instead.

Comment: Unity will use whatever you set to handle desktop, best option is nemo. As far as using an older Nautilus in 20.04 not possible or easily so. The ubuntu-unity-desktop package should take care of desktop handling by nemo for you, it's up to you what your default file manager is (if you leave Nautilus installed..

Comment: @N0rbert starting from 20.04, `nemo` is the default file manager in Ubuntu Unity remix, so from that side, it will be OK.

Comment: Maybe, but the `ubuntu-unity-desktop` meta-package still [depends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/ubuntu-unity-desktop) on `nautilus`. Do not know other way to install Ubuntu Unity "remix".