# How do I install fluxbox in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, uninstall, fluxbox

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to install and then configure and test Fluxbox.

Later, once acquired enough experience, I would proceed to uninstall Gnome.

For the uninstallation of Gnome the suggested post will be very useful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: @N0rbert: Thank you very much for the suggestion, but I will keep Gnome installed until I get some experience with fluxbox.

Comment: @N0rbert: I have come to this answer, due to your kind suggestion. I have found this command concatenation, posted as a method for Gnome removal. I dare to bother you to ask, based on your extensive experience, what you think about them. Thank you very much and excuse me. The command is:  dpkg -l | grep .gnome. | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge -V --auto-remove -yy

Answer (score 3):

To install Fluxbox,first you will want to make sure that you’ve enabled the universe repository.

Open up a terminal window and type in the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install fluxbox
```

You will be prompted for your password, and the installation will continue.

Once you are done installing, you will need to rebooting the computer.

At the Ubuntu Login prompt, click the Options button in the bottom left hand corner.

You will be prompted to choose from a list of Window Managers that are installed on your system.

Select Fluxbox and continue to login.

The main menu can be seen by right-clicking on the desktop.

At the bottom of the screen, you will see a taskbar that shows you the running programs and lets you switch between workspaces.

As long as you have not developed enough experience with Fluxbox, you should not uninstall Gnome.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems simple. I will follow your advice on uninstalling Gnome.

Comment: I suggest you visit this site:
https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/creating-perfect-fluxbox-desktop-linux/

Comment: The site is excellent, and it has turned out to be very useful. Thanks a lot.