# How to run gnome-terminal from .desktop file in nautilus 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, nautilus

I have several `.desktop` entries that launch the terminal as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=<the name>
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal <commands>
```

Problem: when I click on them from the desktop view, they are executed as expected.
BUT when I'm in nautilus in the Desktop folder, they are only opened as editor file.

Question: how can I force nautilus to execute them, just like on the desktop view?

Comment: It is new feature. Use Nemo or Caja instead.

Comment: Well, this used to work in `18.x`, so I wonder why features are getting removed in new versions?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality was removed.

See references:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1819375
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/184
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115/1

Possible solution is to use Caja or Nemo instead.

Or more radical way - [remove GNOME sHell](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509) and install MATE or Cinnamon instead.