# GNOME errors freeze my system completely - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04, on a 10700k with 32GB of RAM, with no graphics card.
My system freezes and the following GNOME errors pop up in the system log.
The PC has to be force restarted sometimes.

[image: Screenshot of errors in system log]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: @N0rbert   I want to keep using GNOME and solve the issue. Unless GNOME is broken, which probably is not the case.

Comment: Do you have many Gnome extensions installed? This particular error is generally found with a coding error that tries to do something on the screen.

Comment: I have it installed but the problem has been here way before I Installed it.

Comment: Screenshots of text are not useful, instead you should be copying this into the post as text instead of screenshots.