# Alternate DE for Gnome, but there is a criteria

Tags: software-recommendation, window-manager

Only thing I like about gnome is that like Android, I cam switch between programs by moving my mouse pointer to the top left corner. I think its the mutter WM. Other than that, gnome is too heavy on my old spec system.
The image shows the task switching scheme

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

So my question is, is there an alternative DE for gnome, but still having the task switching ability I described above? Is it possible to add such feature on any other DE like MATE/Cinnamon etc?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632195/alternate-de-for-gnome-but-there-is-a-criteria

Comment: Is it not allowed?

Comment: Not generally. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/991/70524

Comment: I deleted the other one

Comment: With compiz window manager you can set hotcorners. Compiz can be used with Mate and Xubuntu. Hotcorners can be set in Cinnamon desktop. Probably also KDE Plasma.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) Hot corners is supported on MATE with Compiz.