# How do I remove GNOME desktop compeletely after installing KDE?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, kde, gui

I try to use KDE desktop a couple days, I think I like it and I don't wanna go back with GNOME. What will I do to remove it completely? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 by the way

Thanks

Comment: Personally I'd leave both on your system, just so when you want to, you can select the Ubuntu (or GNOME) desktop at login and use that when certain workflows make sense for you with that desktop, or just for a change (I write this as a multiple-desktop user).   You can `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop` however it may remove more than you want (when you `autoremove` later on especially) as there maybe some apps you'll miss; that were included with the Ubuntu/GNOME desktop - ie. read what will be removed before you accept it.

Comment: Also be aware of how you installed KDE.  My assumption in the last comment was that you `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` (ie. you have it all, and not selectively added components).  If you individually installed components, the effect of the command I gave in the last comment will have greater effects and you risk being left without a working GUI (esp. after the `autoremove`) but this won't impact you if you installed all of KDE via kubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) - follow this carefully.

Comment: @N0rbert I think so. Thank you