# Ubuntu 20.04 on VirtualBox is slow after updating from 19.10

Tags: boot, virtualbox, systemd

I've been running Ubuntu 19.10 for awhile with no problem. Very snappy, quick, and easy to use. I just got updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and it takes ages to boot (15-20 minutes). Even once its booted, the OS is choppy, slow, and bulky. I can't get any work done with this happening. This is what I get when I run system blame.

[image: attached is image of my terminal with the system analyzed]

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 reached EOL July-2020 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/) so just being updated doesn't ring true with a used system... You've also tagged Lubuntu, but mention Ubuntu  (your picture also shows what looks very like a GNOME desktop and not a LXQt one).  So please clarify   (and please don't provide pictures of text)  Does your VM provide the minimum specifications required to run Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS?

Comment: Save your data back to the host system and create a new install on a new virtual disk. 20.04 and 20.10 should feel faster than before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: I didn't have this problem on my initial setup. Then I went and added more CPU cores (it was 1) and the boot time start going crazy long!

Bringing back CPUs to 1 stopped it from happening.

Not sure the actual reason behind it though.

I tested with 12 and 6 cores and all the same - slow boot.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which of these are doable for you, but here are a few solutions that might help:

### 1. Make a new VM

You can create a new VM in virtualBox, reinstall ubuntu, and get your files back via cloud,  shared folders....

### Use a dual-boot

Not all computers play nice with dual-boot, especially when there is not much storage availible. But since you are using VM's, storage will not be much of an issue. If you see high memory usage during your VM session (>70%), this might be the only solution.