# Ubuntu runs slowly on i3-7130U

Tags: 20.04, performance, 21.10

I have a computer with Intel Core i3-7130U (Kaby Lake) CPU and Intel HD Graphics 620 integrated GPU.

For an unfathomable reason, any Linux distro I run, including the wonderful Ubuntu 21.10 or 20.04, runs slowly. It’s sluggish overall. Things like animations lag. Everything takes an extra second to happen. When I try to select text, it takes a second or two before the highlighting appears. It’s super frustrating relative to Windows, where everything feels much snappier. But I like Linux, esp. Ubuntu.

Besides obviously upgrading to a better PC, what can I do to fix this? I heard Ubuntu kills Windows when it comes to performance.

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328626/same-specs-but-ubuntu-is-more-sluggish-than-windows-why) no longer works :(
[Detailed specs](https://pastebin.com/raw/SLfWPDqD)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Some things to review & links to even more. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Stock Ubuntu (gnome) is a piece of shit and lagged a lot on my PC as well. I would recommend Xubuntu or Kubuntu. Both are fast but kubuntu wasn't as polished as manjaro when I tested it and I faced graphical glitches, so I stuck to Xubuntu. By default xubuntu uses an ugly theme, so to make it look good I use Arc Dark app theme + Numix WM theme + papyrus dark icons + picom compositor [with rounded corners and dual kawase blur]. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/Qf0QMTK)