# Running a shortcut

Tags: 20.04, directory, shortcuts

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and I am quite disappointed!

It looks like you cannot start a program shortcut from the any folder! If the shortcut is on the desktop, you can right click on it and "Allow Launching" the program ... but that option does NOT exit for folders, even for the system folder "/usr/share/applications" !!!

Is there a way to allow all the shortcuts to launch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: @N0rbert, that is not serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably from the point of view of security and organization, nautilus does not anymore support executing a file by double clicking it. The idea is that applications should be started from an icon in the Application overview, or from a command in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog or the terminal.

Custom launchers therefore should reside in your `~/.local/share/applications` folder or in system wide folders. From there, they are automatically included in the application overview, and can be placed on the dock as a favourite, or arranged in folders in the application overview.

Still, you could configure your desktop to launch applications when double-clicking a `.desktop` launcher in the file manager.

- Install `dex`. This is a command line tool that allows running any `.desktop` file from the terminal. Install from the command line with `sudo apt install dex`
- Create a `.desktop` launcher for `dex` in `.local/share/applications` that launches `dex` according to `Exec=dex %U` (see example below).
- In your file manager, associate `.desktop` files with that launcher using Right-click, Properties, "Open with" tab.

Following is an example `.local/share/applications/dex.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run desktop launcher
Comment=Runs .desktop files
Exec=dex %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

A more fundamental approach would be to move to a file manager that supports launching executables, or switch to a different desktop that supports this out of the box.

Comment: I like your suggestion about DEX and I'm going to try it. I find that Canonical did a bad move with gnome. It was working fine before there was no reason to change that feature.

Comment: I can't get it to work ... the ./local/share/applications/dex.desktop shortcut is correct as far as I know, I set it to execute from terminal and I see the terminal windows flashing when I start any other shortcut, but the requested program is not  starting!

Comment: Does not need to be executable. Instead, you need to associate desktop files with it in the file manager.

Comment: the desktop shortcut are associated with DEX, the problem is that I see flashing the terminal windows in which DEX execute, but the program shortcut that started it does not execute.

Comment: I added an example desktop file which is still on my system. I usually test my answers first.

Comment: I replaced my own dex.desktop file with yours and it works! Thank you.

Comment: Please "accept" the question (check the mark next to the question) if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a shortcut on desktop home screen then you just have to go to `Menu > Test App > Right Click > Add to Home Screen`. If this still doesn't work then check the app properties in `/home/user/desktop/app > Properties` and then configure the app type, if it's in wrong format then check it's in correct path or not `/usr/bin/app-name %U`. If it still doesn't work, try launching from terminal **and creating that a text executable file on desktop**, the format can be like this: type the exact system-name for the application - `$app-name`.

Hope this will help you add a desktop shortcut :)

Comment: I don't see where to start here. What is this "Menu" you refer to? And then what is that "Test App"? I think it will be difficult for readers to follow.