# can not disable nautilus file manager(ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, themes

i want to use nemo file manager as default desktop manager (icons) but i can not disable nautilus desktop icons

i tried
to disable it in gnome tweaks but it didn't work

i tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

i tried to delete

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop
```

but there was no such a file in that directory

when i run command `nemo-desktop` it shows me:

```
** (nemo-desktop:6271): WARNING **: 19:47:56.972: Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Pop-dark) - checking...

** (nemo-desktop:6271): WARNING **: 19:47:57.103: Desktop already managed by another application, skipping desktop setup.
To change this, modify org.nemo.desktop 'ignored-desktop-handlers'.
```

i'm new to linux please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: no i do not want to remove gnome desktop environment i just want to chagne my desktop manager (desktop icons) from nautilus to nemo.