# How to add desktop icons in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (for example: Firefox, Thunderbird)?

Tags: icons

How do I add desktop icons in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS? I have been trying to find out how to do this for about an hour now by looking in the web, but all the tutorials are kind of confusing.

I didn't know it was this hard in Ubuntu, because it only takes about 4 mins to do in Windows.
I want to make a desktop icon for an app called cloud compare. I open other locations in Ubuntu file manager and went to computer and did these following steps: /usr/share/applications. I couldn't find the cloud compare file.

Thanks.

Also don't hesitate to ask for more info.

Comment: What desktop envoirnment are you using? The default one for Ubuntu 20.04? Or a different one, like KDE Plasma.

Comment: There are many desktop files in /usr/share/applications (firefox and thunderbird among them).  Just copy the ones you want onto your desktop.

Comment: How can I do it with downloaded applications (for example: Balena Etcher)? It worked with Firefox thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: Here is my explanation how to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut/1437386#1437386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to add an an icon from the Application overview to your desktop. Instead, you need to find the `.desktop` file of the application and copy it over to your "Desktop" folder. These text files with a `.desktop` extension will usually be in either `/usr/share/applications`, for applications installed using APT (".deb packages"), or in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`, for snap packages.

*Background*

The workflow of having application icons on your desktop, such as it was when Windows 95 appeared in 1995, has been kind of deprecated by the Gnome Shell developpers.

- These icons are not accessible while you work: your windows will cover them.
- It can involve a security risk if any user, or perhaps malware, can place any executable on the desktop

In principle, application icons are installed from trusted sources by your system administrator (that will likely be yourself on your own computer). Conventional installers will automatically install a launcher in dedicated places, from where they are picked up in the application menu.

- It takes hitting <kbd>Super</kbd> then typing a few letters to launch any of the installed applications
- If you use the application quite regularly, drag it to the first page in the Application Overview, where you will see it immediately when you open that view (Shortcut key: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>).
- If you use it very frequently, place it on the Dock as a favourite (right-click the icon, select "Add to favorites" and optionally drag the icon on the desired place on the dock). You have one-click access, even while you are working (i.e., other windows are open). You can also access these applications with a single shortcut key, i.e., <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for the left most application on the dock, etc.

That said about Gnome Desktop, Ubuntu reintroduced support for Desktop icons through a dedicated Gnome Shell extension. That is mainly intended to host your current user files, however, you can also place application launchers there by copying `.desktop` files to the Desktop folder.

Comment: I've been using Linux since ... the early 90's, and this is one of the stupidest things about using Linux.  It's hard to argue that that Linux is good on the desktop when you can't do this one simple thing with a right click.

Comment: @DGM Opinions differ. I never use the desktop or desktop icons because this is clutter guaranteed, so for myself, it is a non-issue. Ubuntu happens to use a desktop environment that does not support desktop icons, and hacks it in. This is why it can feel limiting. Other linux desktops fully support desktop icons.