# Shortcut to program installed via binary installer

Tags: shortcuts, chmod, jre

I'm looking for a little help with Ubuntu 18.04. I installed a program using the below terminal commands:

```
su          
"password"   
cd Documents    
chmod +x WatchPower64.bin     
./WatchPower64.bin
```

The program does work as expected once installed. It has installed to the /root/WatchPower folder. There are some jar and lax files in this folder plus jre and lib folders.
If I close the program/reboot the machine I have to repeat the process to install the program as I can't figure out (being an ubuntu novice!) how to create shortcuts etc. When I 'hover' over the taskbar the program shows as 'com-zerog-lax-LAX' if that helps?

Could I get some advice on how to create a desktop shortcut or a taskbar link to launch the program quicker please?

Comment: User programs should generally be installed to the folder `/usr/local/bin`. You still need to ensure proper permissions. You should then be able to create a shortcut, just as you would with any other program.

Comment: If this is "just" about creating a desktop shortcut, I believe it's a duplicate. [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu system, or at least a fundamentally modified one. `su` will not work on an Ubuntu system, because the root account is not enabled.

Comment: I understand that `WatchPower64.bin` is a binary installer that you ran? Did the installer display to you the command to run program? If the program is installed in `/root/WatchPower` folder, there should be some main executable file in this folder - browse its contents and try to identify the executable. You should use this executable as command to run the program again without reinstalling. Maybe there's some help file there? BTW. Does the program really needs to be installed in root's folder and run as root? Generally one shouldn't run programs as root unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: "/root/WatchPower" That is a potential security breach. Please do not do this.

Comment: The program seems to want to install to the /root/ folder by default. I now know this is bad so change the install options. Yes it is a binary installer. The installer is an 'anywhere install'. I checked the /share/applications folder and there was a watchpower shortcut but it was directing to root installation which didn't work. I removed this and reinstalled to bin folder but the shortcut doesn't recreate. I tried to create a desktop shortcut but there doesn't seem to be a launcher in the watchpower folder just jax and lax files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a launcher just as with any other application (it is irrelevant that the program was "installed via binary installer").

There are a lot of guides out there, see sources below.
Probably the easiest way:
Launch the application. Then go to the dash, right click on its icon and *Add to Favorites*.
You can later fine tune many properties of the launcher.

Besides, you should avoid working as root. For any operation requiring admin privileges you should use `sudo`.
You would rather place the executable somewhere available for anyone.

**Sources**

1. [How to make a desktop shortcuts on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232612/how-to-make-a-desktop-shortcuts-on-ubuntu-20-04)
2. https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-for-any-app-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/
3. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux